# Access a file on remote/cluster directly

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, meld

I am trying to compare two files one local and other one on remote. I used

```
meld a.txt user@host:/home/user/john/b.txt
```

This was not possible because file could not be detected. However, I could copy the same file from the same location to local via `scp` and do the comparison afterwards. How to access the file directly on cluster for example like:

```
vim user@host:/home/user/john/b.txt
```

Comment: SO is for programming questions only, so OS/app support is [off-topic](/help/on-topic). You can ask on [ubuntu.se] instead.

Answer (score 3):

In bash, you can create a file from a process with `<(...)`:

```bash
meld a.txt <(ssh user@host cat /path/to/file/b.txt)
```

---

If you want to modify the remote file, you'll have to use some mounting.

One way to do it is to use [sshfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS)

```
# sshfs setup
mkdir ~/remote
sshfs user@host:/path/to/file ~/remote

# meld invocation
meld a.txt ~/remote/b.txt
```

Comment: This opens file in read only mode. How to access in read/write mode?

Comment: for that you'll need to mount the remote file locally. see `sshfs`

Answer (score -1):

Try save the remote file to your linux system and simply use `diff -y file1 file2` command. You will see the diff between.

`diffutils` - packagre required for it

Answer (score -1):

Check the path in your example, I think it's incorrect. Try directly:

`vim john@server:b.text`

That should work.